# ORA-01653 Unable to Extend Table AGILE.A_DW_TXN_LOG BY 128 in Tablespace AGILE_DATA3

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am trying to import an oracle database from a dump file. While importing I am getting `ORA-01653 Unable to Extend Table AGILE.A_DW_TXN_LOG BY 128 in Tablespace AGILE_DATA3`.
I have tried to fetch the information about the tablespace with this query and I am not able to understand what these columns hold information about.

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE Tablespace_name = 'AGILE_DATA3';


FILE_NAME                                  |FILE_ID|TABLESPACE_NAME|BYTES      |BLOCKS |STATUS   |RELATIVE_FNO|AUTOEXTENSIBLE|MAXBYTES   |MAXBLOCKS|INCREMENT_BY|USER_BYTES |USER_BLOCKS|ONLINE_STATUS|
-------------------------------------------|-------|---------------|-----------|-------|---------|------------|--------------|-----------|---------|------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
D:\APP\ORADATA\AG934\AGILE_DATA301AG934.ORA|     11|AGILE_DATA3    |26791116800|3270400|AVAILABLE|          11|YES           |34359721984|  4194302|        1280|26789019648|    3270144|ONLINE       |
```

I looked up at this link but as I look into my table I find Auto Extension already enabled. What is it I am not doing correctly here ? I am using `data pump` utility available in sql developer to import the dump file.

Also I hope that when we import the dump file it actually overwrites all of the information already present on the database. Is that correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-01653: unable to extend table by in tablespace ORA-06512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129376/ora-01653-unable-to-extend-table-by-in-tablespace-ora-06512)

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that either all of your tablespace data files have reached the limit of their size supported by the OS (usually 32GB each) and cannot grow, or that the storage media has physically run out of space and they cannot grow. Since the size of the tablespace appears to be about 25GB (the BYTES column) and the upper limit is 32GB (the MAXBYTES column), I'd say it is most likely that your disk is full.

That said, datapump will not automatically empty tables unless you tell it to. By default it will skip existing tables entirely and not load anything. Use the TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION parameter to tell datapump what to do in cases where tables already exist, as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C9664F8C-19C5-4177-AC20-5682AEABA07F.htm#SUTIL936